# .Net - Using Action/Delegate to pass data back up the navigation stack

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have multiple levels of nested classes. I need a  better way to notify my parent class by sending a value up the nested stack.

To expand on the above, in my inner class I have an asynchronous method call. Now I need to notify my parent class once My asynchronous method has completed its execution. Is there a way in which I could use an Action to get the value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try and pass values "up the stack" (which will get very messy, very quickly), might I suggest you implement some kind of [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or other event pattern of your choosing, and have the parent auto-magically notified and avoid trying to return values to the parent "up the stack"?

As a simple example, I'll assume your current predicament is akin to this:

```
public void DoSomething(Action callback)
{
    DoSomethingElse(callback);
}

public void DoSomethingElse(Action callback)
{
    WeMustGoDeeper(callback);
}

public void WeMostGoDeeper(Action callback)
{
    // I have no idea who I am anymore.
}
```

It would be far better to implement even a simple observer/event system.  In essence you'd have some kind of an observer that raises an event (note: this is grossly simplified):

```
public class Observer
{
    public delegate void SomethingHappenedDelegate();

    public void NoReallySomethingHappened()
    {
        if(SomethingHappened != null)
            SomethingHappened();
    }

    public event SomethingHappenedDelegate SomethingHappened;
}
```

You'd create an instance of this class somewhere, and your last function needs to do something along the lines of:

```
whateverTheObserver.NoReallySomethingHappened();
```

*ANY* class can subscribe to this and be notified when something happened.  How you deal with that observer is entirely up to you.  It could be passed down the call-stack, or be available from a factory, or some other accessible class.

Comment: Could you expand on the above implementation for me ? I am quite new to this. Thanks!